# Terminal Command Not Working For Mac After Installing Anaconda

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, spyder

I just installed Spyder through Anaconda for Python on my Macbook Air. I'm trying to launch the App through the terminal but i get this error and have no idea how to solve it. FYI, this is my first time being in the terminal, I'm completely LOST! Any command you see that i ran is what i saw online while trying to solve the problem.Thanks.

[image: The image is the Terminal on Mac]

Comment: Isn't Spyder a GUI app? I think it should be in the Launchpad, with all the other apps

Comment: It's not in the Lunchpad. Only Anaconda is there. I am able to open it the anaconda App but is there something wrong with my command window that is preventing me from opening it through terminal?

Comment: It's a GUI app, you shouldn't be able to open it via Terminal. In the same vein, you can't just type `safari` or `itunes` or, in general, the name of an app to open said app. Command-line programs are a different story, though. I suggest you to install Spyder from its official website and then configure it to use Anaconda, if it doesn't detect it automatically.

Comment: Can you run it through Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to fix your `$PATH`

Run `echo $PATH` to see your current PATH, then add the [Anaconda Path](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/) before it. In `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Once you've updated your bash_profile, you'll need to `source ~/.bash_profile`, or run that same `export` statement in your current shell session.

Comment: this is what i got when i ran the echo $PATH code.                                  
guest@Guests-Air ~ % echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: I'm not sure what my next point of action should be based on your second comment.

Comment: Your PATH is a list of paths to search, separated by colons. So, assuming `/Users/jsmith/anaconda/bin/python` exists on your machine, you'll want to make sure your PATH gets exported as `export PATH="/Users/jsmith/anaconda/bin/python:$PATH"`. (Tells the OS to search anaconda first, then other dirs)

Doing that on the command line will export for your current session. Adding in bash_profile will make sure it persists to new sessions.